# What event to call when ListView selected item changed?

Tags: delphi, vcl, delphi-10.1-berlin

I'd like to run a procedure--once--whenever the selected item in a ListView changes. The obvious choice would be OnSelectItem, but it's called *twice* when the user moves from one selected item to another (using mouse or arrow keys). Similarly, OnChange is called *three* times when moving between items.

Is there an event generated only once under these conditions? OnClick is generated once, but doesn't cover moving between items using arrow keys, etc.

Comment: VCL or FMX please

Comment: It's a VCL app.

Comment: The OnSelectItem event tells you the item being changed and whether it is being selected or unselected. So it makes sense to get two event triggers, one for the old item that is being unselected, and one for the new item that is becoming selected. The OnChange event is also triggered for state changes, so it makes sense for it to be triggered more than once, too

Comment: Thanks, @Remy ... Your solution works as well as the accepted one, i.e., `if Selected then //do something;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it like this using `OnSelectItem`.

- Remember the last selected item.
- When the `OnSelectItem` fires, check if the current selected item differs from the one you remembered.
- If so, perform your task, and make a note of the new selected item.

Comment: Works great. Thank you, David.