# Get Selection Change Event in FMX TListView

Tags: listview, delphi, event-handling, firemonkey

I'd like to run a procedure whenever the selected item in a ListView changes. I can't figure out what event is dealing with this.

There's a post here: [What event to call when ListView selected item changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47778620/what-event-to-call-when-listview-selected-item-changed) that deals with this in VCL, but I'm using FMX.

Delphi 10.3 Rio

Comment: Perhaps the [`OnChange`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.ListView.TListViewBase.OnChange) event? "*Occurs when the `ItemIndex` property changes **as a result of a user selecting a different item**.*" Or the [`OnItemChange`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.ListView.TListViewBase.OnItemChange) event? "*Occurs immediately after **changing the selected item from the list view**.*"

Comment: @RemyLebeau `OnChange` is indeed getting triggered when clicking on another item. However, when adding a new item, and this new item is getting selected as a result, it does not trigger `OnChange`.

Comment: ...And `OnItemChange` get's triggered multiple times when selecting a new item

Comment: "*when adding a new item, and this new item is getting selected as a result, it does not trigger `OnChange`*" - I wouldn't expect it to. That event is for **user**-initiated changes, not **code**-initiated changes.  If you add a new item in code, just call your `OnChange` logic directly for the new item.

Comment: @RemyLebeau that's what I indeed did, but I was assuming there's a correct way of doing it, placing the logic in one place.